# Boolean modifier not working and also material not applied

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have 2 Question mention below

I have attached a file. [image]

Q1. I want to cut the part and im using the boolean modifier. I have rename the layer. In that layer 3 parts can cut (its name is cut) And the one layer without cut its not cutting with the boolean modifier. Plz tell me how it can be cut and reason where im going wrong.

Q2. I cannot apply material to my model. Whats the problem behind the model.

Comment: Unrelated questions should be asked as different posts. One question per post to keep things organized.

Comment: may i know what is unrelated question to be as in different post. The same model is not cut and the same model is not adding the material.

Answer (score 1):

You can expect that behaviour of boolean modifier, if you try to cut in ngons (face with more then 4 vertices). Blender is smart enough to cut it smoothly in other parts of the mesh, but in this particular part, something went wrong. Fortunately boolean works, but not in perfect way. Here you'll see how to fix that and that you can apply material to your mesh without problem.What I didn't show in this short .gif is that you should always have normals pointing outside so you need on all your meshes in edit mode, with all faces selected press CTRL+N to calculate them.
[image]

Comment: it work with boolean modifier but i cant apply the material as ur showing in ur gif but here i cant apply. reason plz

Comment: Yes you can. I just showed you, that it's possible. Maybe you expect for the material color to be visible in solid view mode. You have to switch to rendered or material to see it. After doing that if you still will be insisting, that it's not possible. Make gif of you trying and failing.